# What does the syntax "int x = (2, 3);" mean ? Any special usage?

Tags: c

I was just doing some small C problems and came up with this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int k = (3, 4);
    printf("%d\n", k);
}
```

Could someone explain where is the syntax, `(3, 4)` used for ? Since when does it come from ? I think the problem should be asked before but I don't know how to google for it.

BTW, the above is my simplified version. The origin code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a = -5;
    int k = (a++, ++a);
    printf("%d\n", k);
}
```

Comment: It is just a play on using the *comma operator* within parenthesis. The parenthesis are meaningless, and `3,4` is a use of the *comma operator* where `3` is ignored. Make sure you also [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: Thanks ! dudes. I am searching for it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the parentheses are *not* meaningless there - the comma operator must be parenthesized in an initializer.

Comment: Meaningless to the result, yes you have to have them to compile. Sorry for the confusion.